# Cleanup of statement handlers in DBI perl

Tags: perl, sybase, dbi, resource-cleanup

I am using DBI perl to connect with Sybase dataserver. My process does the following in loop that runs throughout the day

```
Till end of day, do {
  $sth = $dbh->prepare
  execute query
  someAnotherPerlFunction()
  someAnotherPerlFunctionOne()
}

someAnotherPerlFunction()
{
   $sth = $dbh->prepare (select)
   execute query
}

someAnotherPerlFunctionOne()
{
   my $sth = undef;
   $sth = $dbh->prepare (update)
   execute query;
   undef $sth;
}
```

Now, given that this will run throughout the day, what are some of the things that I need to keep in mind in terms of resource cleanup.

Currently, I am doing `undef $sth` after each function, as shown in someAnotherPerlFunctionOne. Is that necessary?

Comment: The undef in someAnotherPerlFunctionOne is not needed. Variables defined inside of the function are undef once it goes out of scope.

Comment: More important is the handle to the database ($dbh). Eventually commits are required, if AutoCommit is turned off in your code, or if you do not keep a persistent connection you might want to call $dbh->disconnect.

Comment: Why are you asking this? Are you having trouble with your program? If so, then please explain the problem, otherwise leave things as they are.

Comment: @Borodin probably because he's trying to write quality code without unexpected situations or unhandled scenarios.

Comment: @JohnDoe: We usually do that by *testing*.

Comment: @user3606329: *"if AutoCommit is turned off in your code ... you might want to call `$dbh->disconnect`"* It seems a little strange to disconnect, which will discard all changes that have been made. The way to commit a transaction is to call `$dbh->commit`, but `AutoCommit` is *on* by default so it's reasonable to assume that the OP hasn't changed it.

Comment: @Borodin: The OP should have simply asked if undef is required to avoid memory leaks. He was assuming $sth is treated as a raw pointer for example *void () { Foobar *foobar = new Foobar(); }* which would leak memory with each call to someAnotherPerlFunctionOne. BTW: AutoCommit and disconnect was meant to be two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl will clean up for you, but it is a good idea to pass your db handle to the functions instead of recreating it every time and destroying it immediately.

Comment: Thanks. I am creatign dbhandler in another config file that gets included in this one. Hence I am not creating dbh over and again.

Comment: @Kraken: It's a ***handle***. A *handler* is something completely different.

Comment: @Borodin dbh is handle correct? That is what i am specifying in a separate config.

Comment: @Kraken: `$dbh` is a *database handle*; it's a data object. A *handler* is a piece of code that handles events of any sort.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to look out for, but using `undef` isn't one of them

- If your process is running all day then you should keep checking that the connection is still live. You can do that using `$dbh->ping`
- You should `prepare` each statement only once. After that you may execute it many times with different bound parameters
- If you ever leave a `SELECT` statement handle without fetching all of its data then you should call `$sth->finish` to reset it

Your pseudo-code is very limited, and doesn't explain much. In particular I don't understand how a config file (a data file) can create a database handle for you. Because you need to check whether a database connection is still active, you also need to be able to reconnect whenever necessary. If that is done in a "config file" then I think you need to readdress your design

Here's a rather more Perlish pseudo-code example of how I think it should work. Every time around the `until ( $end_of_day )` loop the first thing is to check whether the database handle is still valid. If not then *there* is the point when you should establish a connection and `prepare` all of your statement handles

After that, it is best to pass both the database handle and the statement handle to any subroutines. You will notice that, once the `prepare` has been done for each statement handle, the two subroutines collapse to the same code

This needs filling out a lot, but I know almost nothing about your application. I hope it helps

```
use DBI;

my $dbh;

until ( $end_of_day ) {

    my ($sth, $select, $update);

    until ( $dbh and $dbh->ping ) {

        $dbh = DBI->connect(...);

        if ( $dbh ) {
            $select = $dbh->prepare('SELECT ...');
            $update = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE ...');
            $sth = $dbh->prepare('SOME SQL');
            last;
        }

        sleep 10; # Wait before retrying
    }

    $sth->execute();
    someAnotherPerlFunction($dbh, $select);
    someAnotherPerlFunctionOne($dbh, $update);
}

someAnotherPerlFunction {
    my ($dbh, $sth) = @_;
    $sth->execute;
}

someAnotherPerlFunctionOne {
    my ($dbh, $sth) = @_;
    $sth->execute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am doing the following, in the start of the perl script I do `require "$FindBin::Bin/dbconfig.pl";` and in dbconfig I have dbh=DBI->connect.

Comment: @Kraken: That's not really a config file, which is all about setting up data *constants*. You might set up the DSN, username and password from there with `use constant`, but you need to be able to repeatedly check the database connection and reconnect as necessary throughout the day. You would be better off using a proper Perl module and [`Exporter`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Exporter) to pass the values back into your main program.